# What is the last version of nhibernate that supports .Net Framework 2?

Tags: nhibernate

What is the last version of nhibernate that supports .Net Framework 2 ? and is there a big difference between dealing with it and dealing with last version that supports .Net 3.5 ?

Comment: That depends on what you understand on "dealing with it"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Note](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/07/19/welcome-nh2-1-0.aspx)**:

> The series NH2.1.x is the last whose
>   target is .NET2.0

---

**[NHibernate 3 Alpha](http://www.developerfusion.com/news/84984/nhibernate-3-alpha-1-available/)** (full .NET Framework 3.5 support):

> With the 3.0.0 release, NHibernate
>   includes support for LINQ, along with
>   additional features such as:
>
> Along with a long list of bug fixes
>   and improvements, it has several new
>   features including a new strongly
>   typed criteria API called QueryOver;
>   lazy loading of columns; alias
>   delimiting in generated SQL; and
>   support for DetachedCriteria within
>   IStatelessSession. The new release
>   also brings improved support for LINQ,
>   overcoming the HQL limitations of the
>   previous provider.
>
> Upgrading users should be aware that
>   one of the fixes means that null
>   values in dictionaries are no longer
>   silently ignored, which has the
>   potential to break existing
>   application code.